# Creating Dict from different sources

Tags: python, list, dictionary

With Python, I am trying to create a dic using the information from one dataframe and one list.
I need the name of one of the columns and the number of the next columns to select specific parts of the list.

My data frame looks like that:

```
df
       protein_name  LEN  Start    End
0     Ribosomal_S9:  121      0    121
1     Ribosomal_S8:  129    121    250
2    Ribosomal_L10:  100    250    350
3             GrpE:  166    350    516
4           DUF150:  141    516    657
..              ...  ...    ...    ...
115      TIGR03632:  117  40149  40266
116      TIGR03654:  175  40266  40441
117      TIGR03723:  314  40441  40755
118      TIGR03725:  212  40755  40967
119      TIGR03953:  188  40967  41155

[120 rows x 4 columns]
```

And my list looks like this:

```
Sequence:
'GRRKNAIARVFAMPGEGRIIINNRPLSEYFGRKTLETIVRQPLDLTGTASRFDIMAKVQGGGISGQAGAIKLGIARALIQADPNLRPVLKKAGFLTRDPRMKERRKYGLKKARRAPQYSK...'
```

I need a dic like that:

```
{'Ribosomal_S9:': 'GRRKNAIARVFAMPGEGRIIINNRPLSEYFGRKTLETIVRQPLDLTGTASRFDIMAKVQGGGISGQAGAIKLGIARALIQADPNLRPVLKKAGFLTRDPRMKERRKYGLKKARRAPQYSK',Ribosomal_S8: PLDLTGTASRFDIMAKVQGGGISGQAGAIKLGIARALIQADPNLRP, ...}
```

Before using the loop (That is how I think, that can be done), I have created the dic with only the first name.

```
Dict = {df.iloc[0,0]: Sequence[df.iloc[0,2]:df.iloc[0,3]]}
output:
{'Ribosomal_S9:': 'GRRKNAIARVFAMPGEGRIIINNRPLSEYFGRKTLETIVRQPLDLTGTASRFDIMAKVQGGGISGQAGAIKLGIARALIQADPNLRPVLKKAGFLTRDPRMKERRKYGLKKARRAPQYSKR'}
```

After that, I have tried to use this approach in a loop for but I found so many problems.
How can I itinerate this? any advice

By the way, if I made any mistake creating the dic previously or any misunderstanding with the concepts, please let me know I am new in this field.

Comment: What determines the value in the dictionary, how is it related to the sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in the right way.

Just replace the "variables" when you put it in the for loop. Like this:

```
mydict = {}
myseq = 'GRRKNAIARVFAMPGEGRIIINNRPLSEYFGRKTLETIVRQPLDLTGTASRFDIMAKVQGGGISGQAGAIKLGIARALIQADPNLRPVLKKAGFLTRDPRMKERRKYGLKKARRAPQYSK'
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    mydict[row['protein_name']] = myseq[row['Start']:row['End']]
```

Using names to select your columns could be more intuitive.

Comment: @ManoloDominguezBecerra Be careful, `iterrows()` is notoriously sluggish.